# jQuery not calling first time when file change

Tags: jquery, vue.js

when I add or change a file first time, console.log or alert not firing, but 2nd time onward it's firing. And alert is firing two times 2nd time onward. i'm adding this input fields dynamically. please give me a solution. I use jQuery here for change the input file name when selecting new file.

when i add or change a file first time, console.log or alert not firing, but 2nd time onward it's firing. i'm adding this input fields dynamically. please give me a solution. i use jQuery here for change the input file name when selecting new file.

```
<div v-for="document_file in documentArray ">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input
                type="file" ref="file"
                @change="setFile(document_file.id,$event)"
                accept="application/pdf"
                class="custom-file-input"
                name="document_file"
                v-bind:id="document_file.id"
            />
            <label v-if="document_file.file_name" v-bind:id="document_file.id"
                    class="custom-file-label selected">{{document_file.file_name.split('###')[1]}}</label>
            <label v-bind:id="document_file.id" v-else class="custom-file-label selected">{{document_file.file_browse_name}}</label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

setFile(id, e) {
    let self = this;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function () {
        self.documentArray.forEach(function (element) {
            if (id == element.id) {
                element.file = reader.result;
                element.file_browse_name = e.target.files[0].name;
            }
        });
    };

    $('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {
        console.log(e.target.files[0].name);

        $(this).parents('.custom-file').find('.custom-file-label').text(e.target.files[0].name);
        alert(e.target.files[0].name)

    });

},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the console.log directly inside your setFile function, because vue.js is reactive it fires the change event on that function in the first place, because you have bound the function setFile to it with the @change line in your sourcecode. I don't see why you're using the second eventhandler with jQuery anyways. It fires from the second time onwards, because you attach the eventListener with jQuery inside the setFile function which has to be called at least one time with the change event you bound with @change. You could also try to move the jQuery eventListener outside the setFile function.

This should work:

```
<template>

    <form>
       ....
        <input type="file" ref="file" :id="'myID'" 
@change="setFile('myID',$event)"/>

        ....
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    setFile(id, e) {
      console.log(id, e.target.files[0]);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: why i'm using jqury is, it is not changing input file name when i select a new file, so i had to do it with jquery. when console put directli inside the setFile function it works, but what i want is firing it inside the jquery part.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by adding @click function

```
<input
                            type="file" ref="file"
                            @change="setFile(document_file.id,$event)"
                            accept="application/pdf"
                            class="custom-file-input"
                            name="document_file"
                            v-bind:id="document_file.id"
                            @click="setFileName"
                        />
            setFileName(){
                $('input[type=file]').change(function (e) {
                    $(this).parents('.custom-file').find('.custom-file-label').text(e.target.files[0].name);
                });
            },
```